# Serving virtual files in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a page as part of my IIS 7 (ASP.NET) website which serves images from a database. It uses a querystring to select the image and sets the content type header appropriately (image/jpeg) so that, for example, image.aspx?ID=1234 will be displayed in the browser as a jpeg image.

What I want to do instead is offer a URI formed in a manner such as image/1234.jpg which will produce the same result. In other words, there is no actual file on the server named 1234.jpg, it's just the contents of a database record, but from the browser's perspective, it will appear as if there is such a file.

I'm sure this is possible, but I can't figure out how it's accomplished, or where to look for answers. I'm thinking it may be done with an ISAPI filter, but I haven't found an accessible path into the docs to know if that's even the correct basis for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the best option here would be to implement a URL rewrite rule that changes `image/1234.jpg` to `image.aspx?ID=1234`

You can find more on URL rewrite for IIS [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

If, for whatever reason, URL rewrite isn't an option to you, then another possible method might be to implement a custom 404 page. When your request to image/1234.jpg doesn't result in a real file, it'll end up there.

You should be able to detect the URI at that point and serve up the image.

Comment: URL rewrite is providing exactly the result I was after.

Comment: After tinkering with the URL rewrite for IIS, I learned that I could use Application_BeginRequest in global.asax to do a rewrite too. Not as "friendly" as the rewrite plug-in, but has the advantage of working exactly the same in the development server as in IIS.